# Ways to keep a Typescript library API declaration coherent with its implementation?

Tags: typescript, api-design

## Project structure description

In my library named `mylib` I have an API declarartion file **src/mylib.d.ts** written by hand. There is a  reason for write it manually: I want to design an API first and then to implement it (while the `tsc` with `--declaration` flag does the opposite - it generates an API declaration from implementation).

Content of **src/mylib.d.ts**:

```
declare module "mylib" {
  export interface Animal {
    walk(): void;
  }
  export class Dog implements Animal {
    constructor(name: string);
    walk(run?: string): void;
    bow(): void;
  }

  export function randomAnimal(): Animal;
  export const version: string;
}
```

At the package build stage this file can be copied as **dist/index.d.ts** (to be referenced by `"types":"./dist/index.d.ts"` setting in `package.json`) or just published as @types/mylib.

The API implementation code located is in **src/api.ts**:

```
import * as mylib from "mylib";
import { Cat, Mouse } from "./other-animals"
import { logger } from "./logger"

export class Dog implements mylib.Dog {
  walk(run?: string): void {
    logger(`I'm a dog and i ${run ? "run" : "walk"}.`);
  }
  bow(): void {
    logger("bow-wow!");
  }
}

export function randomAnimal(name?: string): mylib.Animal {
  if (name) console.log("you passed name param. It wasn't documented but ok");
  // logger(mylib.version); //if you decomment this line, the bundler will
  // fail with error because "mylib" module doesnt really exists yet. It's OK because in
  // library source code i reference `mylib.d.ts` only for type imports.
  // Or we can just add "paths": { "baseUrl": "src", "mylib": ["./api.ts"] } to tsconfig.json so
  // bundler will use it to resolve module.
  return new Dog();
}

export const version = "1.0.0";
export const undocumentedVar = 123;
```

This file i entry point for bundler: `esbuild src/api.ts --bundle --outfile=dist/index.js --format=esm`.

As result there will be 3 files in npm tarball: **dist/index.js**, **dist/index.d.ts** and **package.json**

## The problem

The problem is that everything declared in **mylib.d.ts** are independent from it's implementation. For example we can remove `randomAnimal` from **api.ts** and project still be compiled without any errors.

My current solution to this problem is next: I add this lines to the end of **src/api**:

```
import * as api from "./api";
const test: typeof import("mylib") = api;
```

And then i run tsc with `--noEmit` and `"files": ["src/api.ts"]` options.

If there will be incoherence between declaration and implementation I will see an error.

It's pretty working solution, but the question is: are there any ways to do it better? For example, without creating additional unexported constant?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty strange way to do this. API (contract) first makes total sense, but instead of writing `.d.ts` files, just write types an interfaces and *not* your implementation.

I don't think writing the `.d.ts` files manually and then the implementation is a pattern that is Typescript really supports.

Comment: Look at vscode example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/vscode.d.ts. This file is definitely written by hand. And then it's published to @types as is.

Comment: Yes it makes sense to write definitions for .js files that already exists. What you're trying to do is just not a workflow that's well supported or intended.

Comment: Can you please give advice on how the current project structure can be changed?

Comment: If you are writing typescript, just write typescript. You can avoid writing implementation by writing interfaces and types first.

Comment: The problem with generating corresponding .d.ts files from .ts is that i actively use tsconfig paths setting to avoid import from "../../../../" expressions in my code. The bundler resolving this paths when generating javascript code, but tsc doesn't while generating .d.ts files.

Comment: Then open a stack overflow question related to that. I'd just really recommend to not adopt a workflow that's so strange and different from the rest of the world. Even if it seems like conceptually a good idea, if anyone else has to use their code they're going to be very confused.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but vscode is written in ts and still has manually written vscode.d.ts file. There must be a reason why such a big project actually use workflow which is different from others. But I don't understand how they solve implementation-declaration-coherence problem (are they are?).