# Why does vscode source code contains vscode.d.ts file which is written manually?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, architecture

Writing .d.ts files manually usually makes sense only if you deal with already existing .js files. If your project written in TypeScript you shouldn't write `.d.ts` by hand - the compiler with `--declaration` option will generate them.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592205/ways-to-keep-a-typescript-library-api-declaration-coherent-with-its-implementati) question i mentioned file https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/vscode.d.ts as example of writing .d.ts file manually. This project is fully implemented in TypeScript. So, why vscode dev team decided to use such an unusual way to make API declaration, instead of generating it from source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they want to define the interface, `vscode.d.ts`, separately from the implementation. You can find the implementation of the `vscode` module here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/b449c95a8460443ee6bf985bb6c8db63d395e6e6/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHost.api.impl.ts#L1065

If they do not implement something defined in the interface, the compilation fails. You can try it deleting the property `version`.